# Piping camera output to two processes

Tags: python, image, opencv, raspberry-pi, pipe

I have the following problem:
We would like to use the output of a raspi camera as input data for two different processes. One sending the camera data over RF link and the other should do some image processing using opencv

like this:

```
    #read camera stream using raspivid
    raspivid_comm = ["raspivid", "-w", str(width), "-h", str(height), "-fps", str(fps), "-b", str(video_bitrate),
                     "-g", str(keyframerate), "-t", "0"]
    raspivid_comm.extend(extraparams.split())
    raspivid_comm.extend(["-o", "-"])
    raspivid_task = Popen(raspivid_comm, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True,
                          shell=False, bufsize=0)
```

the other two processes should use the same stout as input

```
    send_task = Popen(send_via_rf, stdout=None, stdin=raspivid_task.stdout , stderr=None, close_fds=True,
                                  shell=False, bufsize=0)


    improc_task = Popen(improc, stdout=None, stdin=raspivid_task.stdout , stderr=None, close_fds=True,
                                  shell=False, bufsize=0)
```

But the problem is reading the same pipe by two processes (raspivid_task.stdout) does not work.
Is there a possibility to duplicate the output pipe in python?
Like for example the command "tee"?

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to send the output of one program to two others is with `tee` and *"process substitution"* like this:

```
raspivid | tee >(processA) | processB
```

However, that is all in *"lock step"*, so it depends how *"coupled"* you want/need things to be. If the RF link goes down or locks up, is it ok if the image processing stops too? What about the other way around? It also depends on whether you can handle missing a frame or two for the image processing or the RF link.

The simplest way to do it is if everything is decoupled. So you have one process that reads video frames from the camera and puts them into **Redis** or multiprocessing shared memory as fast as possible. Then you have your image processing running in a separate, independent process that reads frames from **Redis** or shared memory as fast as it wants and likewise another process reading from shared memory or **Redis** as fast as it wants and sending the frames out over radio link.